# Not all devices found after search via local network

Tags: c#, uwp, udp, upnp, local-network

I use Udp socket to search devices in local network. 
I need it to discover 2 things

1. IP address
2. Device name(for user friendly UI)

To achieve it I send next request

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:ssdp:all\r\nMX:3\r\n\r\n
```

But unfortunately I don't receive all devices in local network, but in Network(in my PC) I see all devices(hundreds)

Maybe someone help me, how I can receive this two things using UWP.

Comment: There is no way to discover every device in the network like that. With a M-SEARCH you can discover UPnP devices, and that's it. I have no idea what kind of app _"Network (in my PC)"_ is but it probably uses other technologies as well -- network file sharing (CIFS, SMB) and zeroconf (Bonjour) would be some obvious candidates.

Comment: Network (in my PC) this is default Network part in "My Computer"
Also I tried to use Zeroconf, the same result

Comment: Okay, Also it would be great, if I can ran upnp service on the machine in local network, and then find it